# How do I execute native SQL with tortoise ORM

Tags: python, native-sql, tortoise-orm

I want to use tortoise ORM to execute native SQL. What should I do? I can not find the methods or class to do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of `execute_*` [methods](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/databases.html?highlight=execute#tortoise.backends.base.client.BaseDBAsyncClient.execute_insert) at your disposal to execute a raw SQL code. Below is a basic example from the official [documentation](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/basic.html?highlight=execute#manual-sql):

```
"""
This example demonstrates executing manual SQL queries
"""
from tortoise import Tortoise, fields, run_async
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise.transactions import in_transaction


class Event(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.TextField()
    timestamp = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)


async def run():
    await Tortoise.init(db_url="sqlite://:memory:", modules={"models": ["__main__"]})
    await Tortoise.generate_schemas()

    # Need to get a connection. Unless explicitly specified, the name should be 'default'
    conn = Tortoise.get_connection("default")

    # Now we can execute queries in the normal autocommit mode
    await conn.execute_query("INSERT INTO event (name) VALUES ('Foo')")

    # You can also you parameters, but you need to use the right param strings for each dialect
    await conn.execute_query("INSERT INTO event (name) VALUES (?)", ["Bar"])

    # To do a transaction you'd need to use the in_transaction context manager
    async with in_transaction("default") as tconn:
        await tconn.execute_query("INSERT INTO event (name) VALUES ('Moo')")
        # Unless an exception happens it should commit automatically

    # This transaction is rolled back
    async with in_transaction("default") as tconn:
        await tconn.execute_query("INSERT INTO event (name) VALUES ('Sheep')")
        # Rollback to fail transaction
        await tconn.rollback()

    # Consider using execute_query_dict to get return values as a dict
    val = await conn.execute_query_dict("SELECT * FROM event")
    print(val)
    # Note that the result doesn't contain the rolled-back "Sheep" entry.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_async(run())
```